# In AWS RDS, what is the difference between "managed" and "fully managed" services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

If I want to set up a PostgreSQL-compatible database on AWS, I have 3 choices:

- Manual: EC2 (spin up an EC2 and manually set up and maintain a PostgreSQL database on the EC2).
- Managed: RDS-PostgreSQL (AWS will set up and maintain the database instances).
- Fully managed: RDS Aurora in PostgreSQL-compatible mode (AWS will set up and maintain the database instances, just like with RDS-PostgreSQL?)

**My question concerns the difference between "managed" and "fully managed"**. Many AWS certification training materials highlight the "fully managed" feature as an advantage that RDS Aurora in PostgreSQL-compatible mode has over RDS-PostgreSQL. I don't understand what the distinction is.

AWS documentation lists these items as the advantage of the "managed" feature of RDS Postgres: "hardware provisioning, database setup, patching and backups". To compare, these are the items that AWS documentation lists as the advantage of the "fully managed" feature of RDS Aurora: "hardware provisioning, software patching, setup, configuration, or backups". As far as I can tell, the only difference between these lists is "configuration". What am I missing?

Note that I am not asking about other differences between RDS Aurora and RDS Postgres. I'm specifically asking about the difference between "managed" and "fully managed".

Comment: These terms come from rds and aurora documentation?

Comment: Yes. If you look at AWS docs, you will find that RDS is described as a "managed" service, whereas Aurora is described as a "fully managed" service. This difference is not highlighted much on AWS docs, but it is very highlighted in various third party educational materials.

Comment: Do you have a link to these "third party" materials? In my view, difference between "managed" or "fully managed" are in same category as AWS difference between writing "delete", "delete me", "permanently delete", "<name-of-resource>" - different names for same thing.

Comment: Here is one example of third party materials describing Aurora's "fully managed" as having advantage over regular RDS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hLmDS179YE Navigate to 2:48:40. The audio describes Aurora as "a fully managed database" and claims "because it is fully managed, it has a greater performance over the regular MySQL/Postgres RDS".

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind could be the aurora has serverless mode, and also aurora storage is different then in rds. Thus maybe these make it more "managed" then rds?

Comment: The "serverless mode" of Aurora is addressed separately on the same slide, the "fully managed" refers to "regular" RDS Aurora. I suspect that the third party training materials are simply incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Your concern is to understand fully managed and managed services.

Let me explain fully managed service with an example of DynamoDB, which is a fully managed service. AWS manages all infrastructure, and software updates, and at the end all you need to do is use the service and maybe set up some IAM permissions to access it.

While in case of managed services it works on the shared responsibility, in short you have more control on it, AWS do not manage at Infra level like security patching, updates, scaling etc.

Now the above explanation of managed and  fully managed services can be linked with multiple AWS services.

Comment: AWS RDS provides updated and patching of "managed" RDS, not the user. So not sure how your definition applies to RDS and aurora.

Comment: Well as per your original question you were specific about fully managed and manged services. For RDS and Aurora could you please mention the exact query, so that I can help you out on this